# what does test indicator mean in ansi x12 message?

Tags: testing, indicator, edi, x12

I just started my career in EDI. I just want to know what does test indicator mean in ansi x12 message. I know about usage indicator. Can anybody clarify me on my query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The test indicator (ISA15) indicates whether an interchange is test or production.

Comment: I think that is usage indicator. Are both the same ?

Comment: If you're talking about the ISA15, then yes.  If you're talking about some other segment/element, then I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the info andrew

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

A test indicator is used to indicate, if an EDI message is a production message (which shall eventually end up in the production system) or a test message (which shall not end up in a production system).

**Motivation behind a test message:**

Usually, EDI infrastructures are set up in one of the following two ways:

```
 a) 1 production EDI system + 1 test EDI system
 b) 1 production EDI system only
```

"EDI System" in such a case would refer to the EDI protocol level, such as AS2 server, OFTP2 server, X.400 mailbox, SFTP server, etc. The system itself could be a cloud-based system or an on-premise EDI system (aka local EDI converter).

Behind these protocol level systems one would then usually find ERP systems. Similar to the EDI system also the ERP system can be available as test system and production system.

In the a) scenario test messages would typically be sent to the test EDI system only. Thus, the test message indicator is not really necessary, because messages will only end up in the test ERP system, which is connected to the test EDI system.

In the b) scenario the production EDI system must be able to detect test messages properly. Exactly for such cases a test message indicator can be used. The EDI system is then able to separate production and test messages and process them accordingly. E.g., do not forward test EDI messages to the ERP system or forward test messages to the test ERP system.